# PHP Array formatting

Tags: php, arrays, variables, formatting

I have the variable $array containing:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => C )
```

I want this array to be converted to two new variables:

```
Variable 1 outputting: A,C
Variable 1 outputting: 'A', 'C'
```

Another example:

```
Array ( [0] => B [1] => C [2] => D)
Variable 1: B,C,D
Variable 2: 'B', 'C', 'D'
```

How can i do this?
Thanks, Laurent

Comment: What should be the result for `Array ( [0] => B [1] => C [2] => D)` ?

Comment: You mean you want 2 string variables matching those labelled 1) and 2) in your question? Look at implode()

Comment: For the first you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). As for the second....

Comment: I'm sorry, if you look at the edit you can see what i meant by the outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complete code...

```
 $array=Array ( "0" => "A" ,
    "1" => "C" ,
    );

  $var1 = implode(',', $array);

  echo $var1;
  echo "<br>";

   $result1 = implode(',',$array);
   $var2 = "'".str_replace(",", "', '", $result1)."'";
    echo $var2;
```

this is working properly...i already check

Answer (score 0):

Use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$result = implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use this in my context?

Answer (score 0):

you can make each of element as array like this:

```
foreach ($array as $a) $$a = $a; // result: $a = "a"; $b = "b";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $array = array ( 'A' , 'C');
    $a = implode(',',$array);
    $b = "'". implode("','" , $array) . "'";
    var_dump($a , $b);
```

update:

or the variable $array can also be written as

```
    $array = array ( '0' => 'A' , '1' => 'C');
```

If you have this array in a variable just use it in place of the $array variable.

Comment: this looks pretty good, but how can i get my current array `Array ( [0] => A [1] => C )` to your format? `Array ( 'A' , 'C' )`?

Comment: $array has 0 and 1 as index for 'A' and 'C'. If you do var_dump($array), you can see the index so basically array('A' , 'C') and  array(0=>'A' , 1 => 'C') are same.